# Battery does not work after servicing?

Tags: battery

The battery of the vehicle which is working fine before servicing at an authorized dealer, suddenly stops working a day after bringing the vehicle back from the service center.

I've faced a problem with my car which was being used regularly and had a battery which was a year old. My mom also faced a problem where her [bike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TVS_Scooty) which was being used regularly and the battery was two years old.

Is is possible that a battery that works fine, stops working immediately after servicing? Could it be that the people at the service center replaced it with an old battery or tampered with it? There seem to be some instances [here](http://www.consumercomplaints.in/complaints/maruti-suzuki-nagpur-maharashtra-c382358.html) and [here](http://www.complaintsboard.com/complaints/maruti-alto-c34440.html). I thought I'd ask here if there could be some other reason for a battery to fail suddenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible and it will be hard to tell what actually happened or whether the incident is just coincidence.

Leaving a door open or key in during a long service could drain the battery and if the battery is old or on its last legs then this could finish it off.

Also check to make sure the battery cables are properly tightened maybe they didn't reconnect it properly?

Are you sure the battery is completely dead or is it just discharged. Either let the car idle for 20-30 minutes or put a battery charger on it and let it set for a few hours to see whether it was just a bit low.

Comment: The service center people came home to check the battery and they say the battery needs to be replaced (bike). They said the battery cells died out (how can that be, when it was working fine until we gave it for servicing?). For the car, they said it just needs to be recharged, and even recharging never helped. We eventually had to replace it. No problems with the connections. The service center has too many vehicles to cater to, to attend to a long servicing. They get the job done as quick as possible.